# Prove by induction that $\frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{2n}{3}$ is an integer.

Tags: proof-writing, induction

The question that I am working on is:

> Prove that $\dfrac{n^3}{3}+\dfrac{2n}{3} \in \mathbb Z \ \forall \ n \in \mathbb N$

The method that I think would be will work for this question is that I say that $3|(n^3+2n)$ and prove that.Would this be a good way to do this question?

So far I have done the following:

1) Base Case
n = 1

$3|n^3+2n = 3|3  \checkmark$


2) Assume, $n^3+2n$ is divisible by $3$ for $n =k, k \in \mathbb N$


$k^3+2k = 3m , m \in \mathbb N$


Let $n = k + 1$ ; Then:


$(k+1)^3 + 2(k+1)$
= $k^3+2k+3k^2+3k+3$


Since $k^3+2k = 3m$


$3m + 3k^2+3k+3$

Now, I'm stuck I don't know what else to do further.

Comment: You have made mistake in the term $(k+1)^3+2(k+1)$ it should be equal to $k^3+3k^2+3k+1 +(2k+2)=k^3+3k^2+5k+3$

Comment: Yes, thanks im going to fix that now.

Comment: so now 3(m+k^2+k+1) is a multiple of 3 so done

Answer (score 6):

not induction, but maybe useful to note:

firstly, since 3 is a prime, we have $n^3 \equiv_3 n$ (Fermat's little theorem)

secondly $2n \equiv_3 -n$ (since $3n = 2n + n \equiv_3 0$)

adding these two results:
$$
n^3 + 2n \equiv_3 n-n =0
$$

Comment: Hi Dave!  Glad to see you're still up to your good old magic tricks!  ***Endorsed!*** for excellent conjuring!  Cheers!

Comment: hi Robert, hope you are thriving! had a few weeks off math due to a severe 'flu, just getting back into study, though progress is, as usual, painfully slow ;-)

Comment: Glad you're back on line! Be well!

Answer (score 2):

$$ { n }^{ 3 }+2n=0\quad mod\left( 3 \right) $$

$${ \left( n+1 \right)  }^{ 3 }+2\left( n+1 \right) =$$
$$={ n }^{ 3 }+3{ n }^{ 2 }+3n+1+2n+2=
\left( { n }^{ 3 }+2n \right) +3\left( n^{ 2 }+n+1 \right) =0\quad mod\left( 3 \right) $$

Answer (score 1):

This will be an addition to the above answers: Note that $n^3 + 2n = (n^3-n)+3n = n(n^2-1)+3n = (n-1)n(n+1) + 3n$, each term of the sum is divisible by $3$, hence $3 \mid n^3+2n \Rightarrow \dfrac{n^3+2n}{3} \in \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 1):

**Proof Using Burnside Lemma:**

Consider a round table with $3$ seats.  The chair at each seat can be selected from $n$ types of chairs.  In how many ways can we arrange the chairs, if two arrangements are considered the same when one can be rotated into the other?

The group of symmetry of the chair arrangement is the cyclic group $C_3$ of order $3$.  This group acts on the chair arrangement via chair rotations.  For any of the two nonidentity elements $g\in C_3$, the arrangements fixed by $g$ are those where all chairs are colored the same, which there are $n$ ways to do so.  For the identity element of $C_3$, all of the possible $n^3$ arrangements are fixed.  Hence, the number of arrangements when rotations are ignored is given by $\frac{1}{3}\left(n^3+n+n\right)=\frac{n^3+2n}{3}$, which must then be an integer.

In general, if the round table has $m$ seats, then the number of all chair arrangements when there are $n$ types of chairs and when rotations are ignored is given by $$\frac{\sum_{d\mid m}\,\phi(d)\cdot n^{m/d}}{m}\,.$$
Here, $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.

Comment: You definitely have advanced knowledge of group theory, and "Burnside" Lemma reminded me of Efim Zelmanov who proved it long times ago. But this question is for beginners who use a little bit of arithmetic to "prove" some "facts" about numbers.

Comment: I know that.  But I noticed the OP got the answers he wanted, so what harm can it be to give an algebraic/combinatorial input to the thread?

Answer (score 0):

$$( k + 1 )^3 = k^3 + 3 k^2 + 3k + 1$$

For $n = k + 1$ $$(k + 1)^3 + 2(k + 1) = k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 2k + 3$$

If $k^3 + 2k$ is divisible by $3,$ it is ovious that $$k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 2k +3=(k^2+2k)+3(k^2+k+1)$$ is dividable by $3.$

Comment: I edit your post to make it more readable and [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

assuming

$\dfrac{k^3 + 2k}{3} \in \Bbb Z, \tag{1}$

we have

$\dfrac{(k + 1)^3 + 2(k + 1)}{3} = \dfrac{k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1 + 2k + 2}{3} = \dfrac{(k^3 + 2k) + 3(k^2 + k +1)}{3}$
$= \dfrac{k^3 + 2k}{3} + k^2 + k + 1 \in \Bbb Z, \tag{2}$

by (1).

***QED!!!***

Comment: Are you using induction here?

Comment: @Zero:  yes, but ***you*** provided the base case ($k = 1$) and the assumption that $3 \mid k^3 + 2k$; I merely finished things off!  Cheers!

Comment: Ok, thank you I appreciate you finishing off the rest.

Comment: @Zero:  you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The last step should have been

$3m+3k^2+3k+3=3(m+k^2+k+1)$ whereupon dividing by $3$ produces an integer.

Comment: ok.Thanks. would it be correct if I write $3(m+k^2+k+1) \in Z$ at the end.

Comment: @Zero You're welcome.  My pleasure!  And yes, of course the expression is an integer.  Note more that after division by $3$, we still have an integer.  And that concludes that which was to be shown.  Kind of cool, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, this is amazing.

Comment: @Zero Induction is a very powerful tool.

Comment: Yes,it sure is.

Comment: @zero Please let mw know how I can improve my answer. I really just want to give you the very best answer I can.

Answer (score 0):

The short way: $T_0=0$ and $T_{n+1}-T_n=n^2+n+1$ are integers.